# Hibernate Restrictions in two tables

Tags: hibernate

I have two Entities...

1.User

```
 private Long id;
 private String name;
 private String lname;
 private Phone phone;
```

2.Phone

```
  private Long id;
  private String number;
  private String ddd;
```

I need make a search in hibernate with restriction (if possible) to get all result where phone.number in user. I know with phone.id its work. but other var not work.

Someone how make this?

Comment: So straight forward to achieve with an HQL query. What have you tried?

Comment: with HQL i dont try yet. i like to know if with restriction works...

Comment: Take a look at [`Restrictions#eq`](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: you say....Restrictions.eq("phone.ddd", "35")...this? in table user.

Comment: Check my answer. By the way, Hibernate manages Entities, not tables.

Comment: i know about entities...but thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform a `createAlias` (`Criteria`'s way to perform a join). Check [this manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(User.class, "user");
c.createAlias("user.phone", "phone"); // inner join by default
c.add(Restrictions.eq("phone.number", "43523452"));
c.list();
```

Comment: Do you really need alias? c.add(Restrictions.eq("user.phone.number", "123456"); doesn't work?

Comment: As far as I know you can do that in hql queries, not in criteria.